# ¿Por qué no me deja dibujar en java?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en java en IntelliJ, he intentado dibujar un triangulo y arrancan un contador de fGS pero no me pinta nada en la ventana. Alguien me puede echar un cable.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;


public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running =false;

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    private final int FPS = 60;
    private double TARGETTIME = 1000000000/FPS;
    private double delta = 0;
    private int AVERAGEFPS = FPS;


    // constructor de la ventana
    public Window (){
        setTitle("Primer Jueogo");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // creaciacion del canvas
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        // recibe entradas del teclado
        canvas.setFocusable(true);

        add(canvas);


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // se crea la ventana
        new Window().start();
    }

    // actualiza el canvas
    int x =0;
    private void update(){
        x++;
    }

    // dibuja el canvas
    private void draw(){
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null){
            // numero de buffers que utilizar el canvas
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //----- Empieza el dibujo
        g.clearRect(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //g.drawRect(x,0,100,100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("" + AVERAGEFPS, 100, 100);

        //------------------------

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }


    // Creacion de los Hilos
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //// Contador de fotogramas

        // Restringir el ciclo a 60 FPS
        long now = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); // Hora actual

        // Controla el tiempo de esjecucion
        int frames = 0;
        long time = 0;

        while (running){
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime)/TARGETTIME;
            // actualiza las variables
            lastTime = now;

            if (delta >= 1){
                update();
                draw();
                // Vuelve a cronometrar FPS
                delta --;
                // tiempo de ejecucion
                frames ++;
                System.out.println(frames);
            }

            // Cronometras cuantos fotogramas hay
            if (time >= 1000000000){
                AVERAGEFPS = frames;
                frames = 0;
                time = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    // arranca el hilo
    private void start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;

    }

    // detiene el hilo
    private void stop(){
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé qué exactamente esperas que se vea pero tu código funciona.

Si pretendes ver los frames que hayas dibujado puedes definir la variable **frames** como campo (field) de la clase y ponerla en el drawString:

```
g.drawString("" + AVERAGEFPS + " --- " + frames, 100, 100);
```

Y si queres un triangulo, pues hay que dibujarlo. A groso modo tu clase podría quedar así:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running =false;

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    private final int FPS = 60;
    private double TARGETTIME = 1000000000/FPS;
    private double delta = 0;
    private int AVERAGEFPS = FPS;

    private int frames;// definimos frames aqui, para poder mostrarla


    // constructor de la ventana
    public Window (){
        setTitle("Primer Jueogo");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        // creaciacion del canvas
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        // recibe entradas del teclado
        canvas.setFocusable(true);

        add(canvas);


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // se crea la ventana
        new Window().start();
    }

    // actualiza el canvas
    int x =0;
    private void update(){
        x++;
    }

    // dibuja el canvas
    private void draw(){
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null){
            // numero de buffers que utilizar el canvas
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //----- Empieza el dibujo
        g.clearRect(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //g.drawRect(x,0,100,100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // mostramos frames
        g.drawString("" + AVERAGEFPS + " --- " + frames, 100, 100);

        // y dibujamos un triangulo (WOW)
        g.drawPolygon(new int[] {10, 50, 10}, new int[] {10, 50, 50}, 3);

        //------------------------

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }


    // Creacion de los Hilos
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //// Contador de fotogramas

        // Restringir el ciclo a 60 FPS
        long now = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); // Hora actual

        // Controla el tiempo de esjecucion
//        int frames = 0;
        long time = 0;

        while (running){
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime)/TARGETTIME;
            // actualiza las variables
            lastTime = now;

            if (delta >= 1){
                update();
                draw();
                // Vuelve a cronometrar FPS
                delta --;
                // tiempo de ejecucion
                frames ++;
                System.out.println(frames);
            }

            // Cronometras cuantos fotogramas hay
            if (time >= 1000000000){
                AVERAGEFPS = frames;
                frames = 0;
                time = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    // arranca el hilo
    private void start(){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;

    }

    // detiene el hilo
    private void stop(){
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Varios detalles:

- No uses Canvas. Es una clase muy antigua que pertenece a AWT, el anticuado primer kit gráfico de Java, que estás metiendo en un componente de Swing (más moderno).
- Puedes dibujar directamente sobre un JPanel, extendiendo el método `paintComponent(Graphics g)`:

  class MyPanel extends JPanel {

  ```
  public MyPanel() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(250,200);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);       

      // Draw Text
      g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
  }
  ```

  }

Por otro lado, ten cuidado con tener varios hilos dibujando a la vez, la GUI no se suele llevar muy bien con multihilos